# Center directional light shadow to the cameras eye

Tags: c++, directx, shadows, shadow-mapping, lighting

I'm currently drawing my directional light shadow using this view and projection:

```
XMFLOAT3 dir((float)pitch, (float)yaw, (float)roll);
XMFLOAT3 center(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

XMVECTOR lightDir = XMLoadFloat3(&dir);
XMVECTOR lightPos = radius * lightDir;
XMVECTOR targetPos = XMLoadFloat3(&center);
XMVECTOR up = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

XMMATRIX V = XMMatrixLookAtLH(lightPos, targetPos, up); // This is the view

// Transform bounding sphere to light space.
XMFLOAT3 sphereCenterLS;
XMStoreFloat3(&sphereCenterLS, XMVector3TransformCoord(targetPos, V));

// Ortho frustum in light space encloses scene.
float l = sphereCenterLS.x - radius;
float b = sphereCenterLS.y - radius;
float n = sphereCenterLS.z - radius;
float r = sphereCenterLS.x + radius;
float t = sphereCenterLS.y + radius;
float f = sphereCenterLS.z + radius;
XMMATRIX P = XMMatrixOrthographicOffCenterLH(l, r, b, t, n, f); // This is the projection
```

Which works prefect if the center of my scene is at `0.0, 0.0, 0.0`. What I would like to do is move the center of the scene relative to the cameras position. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XMFLOAT3 dir((float)pitch, (float)yaw, (float)roll);
XMVECTOR center = XMVectorSet(eye(0), eye(1), eye(2), 0.0); // Se the center to the eye

XMVECTOR lightDir = XMLoadFloat3(&dir);
XMVECTOR lightPos = (radius * lightDir) + center; // Add the center
XMVECTOR targetPos = center;
XMVECTOR up = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

XMMATRIX V = XMMatrixLookAtLH(lightPos, targetPos, up);

// Transform bounding sphere to light space.
XMFLOAT3 sphereCenterLS;
XMStoreFloat3(&sphereCenterLS, XMVector3TransformCoord(targetPos, V));

// Ortho frustum in light space encloses scene.
float l = sphereCenterLS.x - radius;
float b = sphereCenterLS.y - radius;
float n = sphereCenterLS.z - radius;
float r = sphereCenterLS.x + radius;
float t = sphereCenterLS.y + radius;
float f = sphereCenterLS.z + radius;
XMMATRIX P = XMMatrixOrthographicOffCenterLH(l, r, b, t, n, f);
```

Comment: Some explanations would help